# CiviReport - development recognition report

Tags: civireport

We need a donor recognition report that - for lifetime or a period of time (last FY for example) - will count totals per donor and include soft credits in the totals. Is this something that can be done "out of the box" or do I need a custom report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Summary Fields extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) and see if it provides a good foundation for you to add the 'Soft Credit' information to.

Comment: cool. can you +1 as well?